# Angular: Label / flag members of a FormArray

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder

I want to 'label' / 'mark' / flag some members (`FormControl` / `FormGroup`) of a `FormArray` in order to categorize them.

**An example scenario:**
User can generate a set of values (which will be **appended to** the `FormArray`) by 3 ways (say, by uploading an Excel file containing the values, generating values from a back-end service or by adding manually, one by one).

Now, I want to highlight the members by different colors (by applying a class) based on, by which of the above ways they were added (say, for example, highlighted in red if they were appended by uploading an Excel file, green if they were appended by generating from a back-end service and blue if they were added manually).

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Pls try  this in your html component

```
<label [ngClass]="{'red': excelFile, 'green': backEnd, 'blue': manual}">
    My doc
    </label>
```

Your component.ts

```
private excelFile:boolean = false;
private backEnd:boolean = false;
private manual:boolean = true; /* by default setting manual as true*/

uploadExcel(){ /* if upload is frm excel file*/
  this.excelFile = true;
}

fromBackEnd(){ /* if upload is frm back end*/
  this.backEnd = true;
}

Manual(){ /* if upload is frm back manual*/
  this.manual = true;
}
```

Your css file

```
label.red{
  color:red;
}

label.green{
  color:green;
}

label.blue{
  color:blue;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: No, the question is not about adding classes dynamically. That's just an example scenario. Basically, I want to 'label' / 'mark' a `FormControl` by the way of adding it (one of the aforementioned 3 ways) programmatically.